# Access locally hosted web app using mac computer name

Tags: macos, networking, ip-address, hostname

I have a web app running on my local machine.

I want to expose the app on my local corporate network.

I know that I can expose it via the currently assigned ip address as:

```
http://myipaddress:port/index.html
```

However I have figured out my local computer name using

```
scutil --get ComputerName
```

It returns my computer name as `anands`

I have it registered on my /etc/hosts file as

```
127.0.0.1 anands
```

But when I try to expose it via

```
http://anands:port/index.html
```

people on my local network are not able to access it

Comment: Each person who need to modify their hosts file.  Obviously they can't point your computer name to 127.0.0.1 for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your IP address (not localhost 127.0.0.1) and name to the local DNS server (another machine on your local network that is used as DNS server). In this way other computers will know that a corresponding name is located to your IP that they can reach.

The way you have done it, you are telling only to your machine that name and others can't resolve that name to IP without the help of a DNS server

Comment: But the ip keeps changing everyday right as these are dynamic IPs ?

Comment: @Andy - Configured your network not to give out dynamic ip addresses in that case.

Comment: @Ramhound thanks for the suggestion but I do not have control over it in a corporate network

Comment: @Andy - Then speak to somebody who does.  At that point they can solve the problem caused by dynamic addresses or always assign you the same intranet address.